# Validate PasswordBox in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate

Is there a way to show error message in AdornedElementPlaceholder while verifiying PasswordBox.

I have something like this:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="DefaultErrorTemplate">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="placeholder" />
        <Border Background="Red"
                ToolTip="{Binding ElementName=placeholder, Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"
                ToolTipService.InitialShowDelay="0"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Margin="3"
                Width="20"
                Height="20"
                CornerRadius="10">
            <TextBlock Text="!"
                       Foreground="White"
                       FontWeight="Bold"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        </Border>
    </StackPanel>
</ControlTemplate>
```

and im my BaseControlStyle im using that validation

```
<Style TargetType="Control"
           x:Key="ControlBaseStyle">
        <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate"
                Value="{StaticResource DefaultErrorTemplate}" />
```

and it's working like a charm with almost every control that i have(Combobox,DateTimePicker,TextBox) but when i want to use same style for `passwordBox` it doesn't work.

[image]
At picture you can see that it's working with simpe TextBox but not with PasswordBox. I don't know how to extract error message to show it in tooltip i that `AdornedElementPlaceholder`

It's showing error message for Username property

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter username.")]
```

I wan't to achieve same thing with passwordBox to give feedback to user about errors (Constraints) when entering password

Any help is really appreciated.

Thanks in advance :)

EDIT:

I have used this for password property

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter password.")]
[RegularExpression(@"^.*(?=.{8,})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9]).*$")]
[StringLength(maximumLength: 15, ErrorMessage = "Minimum 8 and maximum 15 characters.", MinimumLength = 8)]
public string Password
{
    get { return GetValue<string>(); }
    set { SetValue(value); }
}
```

and bound to that property with PasswordBoxAssistant

```
<PasswordBox behaviors:PasswordBoxAssistant.BindPassword="True"
             behaviors:PasswordBoxAssistant.BoundPassword="{Binding Player.Password, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
             FontSize="{StaticResource defaultFontSize}"
             Grid.Row="2"
             Grid.Column="1"
             Margin="10" />
```

and have made custom PasswordBoxStyle that is `BasedOn ControlBaseStyle`

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type PasswordBox}"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource ControlBaseStyle}">
```

i have done same thing with `TextBox`, but it doesnt work with `PasswordBox`.

**INFO:** And i would like to know why you voted to close this question? if there is an answer to this or even guide, i would be happy to close it myself, if not, please provide me an answer before voting to close it. Thanks.

Comment: How do you set the validation error for the passwordbox? It shows the custom template for me...

Comment: I have updated question on how i bound to Password, and what i did with PasswordBox style.

Comment: Regarding the close vote: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.* Your example was certainly not complete (and still isn't)

Comment: Debug your `IDataErrorInfo` implementation. I don't see it, so I can't know what you did wrong there. I only know that a correct implementation can lead to the desired result (I have a working sample, it's just a bit different from yours)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found an answer.
Had to change

```
<Style TargetType="Control"
       x:Key="ControlBaseStyle">
    <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate"
            Value="{StaticResource DefaultErrorTemplate}" />
```

and put it inside

```
<Trigger Property="Validation.HasError"
         Value="True">
    <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate"
            Value="{StaticResource DefaultErrorTemplate}" />
```

aparently it's only working when inside Trigger, and TextBox can work like default and inside Trigger.

Comment: This is real strange... I can't imagine many reasons for this. One of the few things I could possibly imagine would be a strange implementation behind `behaviors:PasswordBoxAssistant.BindPassword`. If it assigns an error template somewhere, this might indeed get precedence before a normal setter...